# Java Spring + Thymeleaf. Как передать сложный объект в форму?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

Есть два класса Employee и Department. Employee содержит поле department, которое нужно передать в форму. Такое написание не работает th:field="*{department.title}"

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String surname;

    @Column
    private int salary;

    @ManyToOne
    private Department department;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinTable(name = "employees_projects", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id"))
    private List<Project> projectList;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Department {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private long id;

    @Column
    private String title;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Department{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", title='" + title + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "department")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Employee> employeeList;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>New Employee</title>
</head>
<body>
<form th:method="POST" th:action="@{/employees}" th:object="${employee}">
    <label for="name">Name: </label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" id="name"/>
    <br>
    <label for="surname">Surname</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{surname}" id="surname"/>
    <br>
    <label for="salary">Salary</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{salary}" id="salary"/>
    <br>
    <label for="department">Department</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{department.title}" id="department"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Create">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Что не работает? Опишите проблему конкретней, покажите код вашего контроллера.

Comment: <input type="text" th:field="*{department.title}" id="department"/>